# ～なり～なり and ～なりと～なりと

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In all the websites I've seen the grammar ～なり～なり (A or B, either A or B), I've seen the pattern ～なり～なり expressed as ～なり～なり. However, now I've seen in jisho for the entry なりと that the meaning "either A or B" is conveyed as ～なりと～なりと.

https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%A8

Then **I wonder if ～なり～なり and ～なりと～なりと refer to the same and therefore ～なり～なり can be actually expressed as ～なり（と）～なり（と）.**

Besides, in this site

https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18460

I've seen the variation ～なり何なり（と）(A or something). Then, just like before, **apart from the forms ～なり何なり and ～なり何なりと, in the case ～なり～なり and ～なりと～なりと refer to the same, would be possible also the form ～なりと何なりと so that ～なり何なり（と）could be actually expressed as ～なり（と）何なり（と）?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common patterns are:

1. `なん/どこへ/どこから + なり(と)` "anything/anywhere"

   - なんなり(と)お申し付けください。
   - どこへなり(と)行ってしまいなさい。
   - どこからなり(と)攻撃してきなさい。
2. `noun1 + なり (+ noun2 + なり)` "noun1, noun2 or anything/anyone/anywhere"

   - 宝石なり服なり好きなものを買いなさい。
   - 暇だったら勉強なりすればいいのに。
3. `noun + なり + なん/どこ/だれ/いつ + なり` "noun or what-/who-/wherever"

   - フランスなりどこなり、好きなところへ行きなさい。
   - 彼なり誰なりを連れて行け。
   - 日曜日なりいつなり来てください。
4. `verb1 + なり (+ verb2 + なり)`

   - 寝るなりゲームするなり、好きに過ごしてください。

Note that you can safely add と as an option only in pattern 1. There are very few, if any, people who say 宝石なりと服なりと, フランスなりとどこなりと, 寝るなりとゲームするなりと, etc. In other words, it's usually wise not to use なりと freely as a listing particle. I think it is most practical to remember only なんなりと/etc as a special form.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Seeing structured these patterns with なり along with the examples has been really helpful .